# Fedora 15 setting gnome-fallback as default for all users

Tags: gnome, fedora, gconf

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  We just switched from Fedora 8 to Fedora 15. I would like to make gnome-fallback the default desktop environment for all users.  Via google I've found that:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome-fallback'
```

will set it for the current user only.  I've done a little reading about `Gconf` and `gconf-tool2`.

Apparently there's a way to make gconf settings default for all users, but I don't see how gconf associates to gsettings.

What am I missing?

Here's some additional information about what I'm trying to do:

I'm creating a Fedora liveCD which is stripped down for my application. The liveCD needs to come up in gnome-fallback and then every user after that to also use gnome-fallback by default.

I have a service that runs on the liveCD it can run any shell commands that are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command (as root, from a console to avoid the per user setting):

`dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome-fallback'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay getting back to you, but this is not working for me.  I didn't see any mention to dbus-launch on the link you provided.  Could you describe how this works?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. Basically it does a connect to dbus if it's not running to do its work.

Comment: If I log in as root and run `dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome-fallback'` It changes the session-name property for the root user, but does not change it for all users.

Comment: I found this page: http://live.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators maybe you can do this: Go to /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d, look at the 00-upstream-settings and make an 01-sessionname file with a `[org/gnome/desktop/session]` section with the key `session-name='gnome-fallback'` and then a `dconf update` as root.

Comment: Thanks AndreasM!  I did something very similar to what you described.  The only difference was I decided to create my own profile.  It worked beautifully!  This [link](http://www.marcusmoeller.ch/misc/using-dconf-magic-to-change-background-image.html) is very similar.